# Setting the response type for a HTTP GET Request to generic list (IEnumerable<T>) and receive it in Angular using HTTP GET

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a HTTP GET method that returns a generic list `(IENumerable<T>)` of items that can then be read by my Angular application, using http.get.

In my controller class of my MVC project that deals with calls from the angular app, I have the following method:

```
[HttpGet(URLs.CustomField.GetCustomFieldsForMatterAsync)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<CustomFieldGroup>), 200)]
public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomFieldDTO>> GetCustomFieldsByFileIDAsync(int fileID)
{
    // fetches the list from DB, stores in a variable called customFields

    List<CustomFieldDTO> list = new List<CustomFieldDTO>();

    foreach (CustomField customField in customFields)
    {
       switch (customField.CustomFieldType)
       {
          case CustomFieldType.Text:
          case CustomFieldType.DateTime: list.Add(_mapper.Map<CustomFieldDTO<string>>(customField)); break;
          case CustomFieldType.Boolean: list.Add(_mapper.Map<CustomFieldDTO<bool>>(customField)); break;
          case CustomFieldType.Currency: list.Add(_mapper.Map<CustomFieldDTO<decimal>>(customField)); break;
          case CustomFieldType.List:
          case CustomFieldType.Number: list.Add(_mapper.Map<CustomFieldDTO<int>>(customField)); break;
       }
    }

    return list;
}
```

I need to return a generic list of customFields so that the angular project can correctly deal with the property based off of what its type is.
I somehow need to change the return type from `IEnumerable<CustomField>` to `IEnumerable<CustomField<T>>`. Value can be of type: string, bool, int, dateTime.

The closest I have come is by creating an abstract class of CustomField with just the value.

```
public class CustomFieldDTO<T> : CustomFieldDTO
{
   public T Value { get; set; }
}

public abstract class CustomFieldDTO { // bunch of other variables }
```

And by doing this, I can then at least create the GetCustomFieldsByFileIDAsync method as seen above.
But the angular app just does not show any value in the Value property. How do I pass a generic type of items to angular? I cant say: `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<CustomField<T>>), 200)]` as that won't work.

Also tried changing the method to: `public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomFieldDTO<T>>> GetCustomFieldsByFileIDAsync<T>(int fileID)` but then angular says it cant find it????

In angular, I'm doing this:

```
    this.http.get<CustomField<any>>(URLs.GetCustomFieldsForMatter(fileID)).subscribe(customFields => 
    {
        console.log(customFields);
    });
```

Is there any way of making this work?

Comment: Try to replace the `CustomFieldDTO<T>` with `List<object>`

Comment: Hey, this actually worked! No idea why I never thought of that after all that time. 
I'm aware its not ideal (objects an all), but its an answer (if you want to make it an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there problem with Generics, replace the return `CustomerFieldDTO<T>` with `List<object>`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetCustomFieldsByFileIDAsync(int fileID)
{
    List<object> list = new List<object>();

    // More code

    return list;
}
```